# Type mismatch compile error trying to apply a lambda expression in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, java-8

In the following sample Java 8 code, all methods are meant to be equivalent, and all compile except for foo3().

1. Why does foo2() compile but foo3() produces a compile error (see code comment for details)?
2. Why won't javac allow an unchecked cast from Object to T in foo3, but will allow an unchecked cast from Function<Object, Object> to Function<T, T> in foo4()?
3. Of the 4 methods that do compile, which one is best?

I suspect there are some finer points of Java compile-time generics involved here, but they seem unclear to me and far from obvious.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LambdaTest<T> {

  public T foo1(T t) {
    Function<T, T> myIdentity = r -> r;
    return myIdentity.apply(t);
  }

  public T foo2(T t) {
    Function<T, T> identity = Function.identity();
    return identity.apply(t);
  }

  public T foo3(T t) {
    /*  XXX Compile error!
     *  java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
     *  Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to T
     */
    return Function.identity().apply(t);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public T foo4(T t) {
    // unchecked conversion from Function<Object, Object> to Function<T, T>
    return ((Function<T, T>) Function.identity()).apply(t);
  }

  public T foo5(T t) {
    // provide an explicit type hint to the compiler
    return Function.<T>identity().apply(t);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hello = "Hello world!";
    LambdaTest<String> test = new LambdaTest<>();
    System.out.println("1. " + test.foo1(hello));
    System.out.println("2. " + test.foo2(hello));
    System.out.println("3. " + test.foo3(hello));
    System.out.println("4. " + test.foo4(hello));
    System.out.println("5. " + test.foo5(hello));
  }
}
```

Comment: My preference would be `foo5`.  As to why `foo3` doesn't compile: I don't really understand all the type inference rules, but I'm guessing that you're just asking too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `foo2` works because in the statement `Function<T, T> identity = Function.identity();` the type parameter of the `identity` method is chosen to be `T` automatically (see [javadoc §18.5.1: generic method applicability testing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1)). However in `foo3`, `Function.identity()` creates a raw `Function` object and the return type of the `apply` method of a raw `Function` object is `Object`. (Automatically choosing the type argument only works if the type argument is an argument of the last expression evaluated before the assignment expression)
2. Cast in `foo4` is allowed since explicit casts are allowed as long as there is no information that `Function` can never be cast to `Function<T,T>`. (see [java language spec 15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)). Also an unchecked cast actually **is** allowed in `foo3` too. The following `foo3` method is perfectly valid:

   ```
   public T foo3(T t) {
       return (T)(Function.identity().apply(t));
   }
   ```
3. `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo5` have about the same "quality". I'd choose `foo5` because it's the shortest one and is at least as readable as the other 2 methods.

Comment: As far as I interpret JLS§5 `foo4` should compile without warnings as a casting context should provide a target type for the type inference of the generic invocation (and after inferring `<T>` for `Function.identity()` the cast can be proven correct at compile-time). But it doesn’t surprise me that the actual `javac` implementation has a different opinion…

Answer (score 5):

`foo3()` doesn't work because it has not been given a type to calculate it with.

A similar problem would occur with Collections.emptyList() and this code with no lambdas:

```
public void bar1()
{
    //Works
    List<String> list = Collections.emptyList();
    String s = list.get(0);
}

public void bar2()
{
    //Compile error
    String s = Collections.emptyList().get(0);
}

public void bar3()
{
    //Works
    String s = Collections.<String>emptyList().get(0);
}
```

The [Java tutorial for generic type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) describes the rules well - the 'target types' section is most relevant.

In bar1() and bar3(), the compiler can infer the generic parameter for `emptyList()` from the return value.  This works from Java 5 onwards.

From Java 8 onwards, generic types can also be inferred from method parameters.  So the following code:

```
public void bar4()
{
    String s = readFirstElement(Collections.emptyList());
}

private <T> T readFirstElement(List<T> list)
{
    return list.get(0);
}
```

will compile fine in Java 8, but fail in earlier versions.

But the compiler won't infer generic parameters from chained method calls, which is why you need to give the explicit 'hint' for the type parameter to the compiler as in foo5().

Comment: Thanks, excellent and correct answer. Wish I could accept more than one. The accepted answer more clearly addressed question parts 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

`Function.identity()` is a static generic method which has its own type, and `T foo3(T t)` needs **another** type T. So it is necessary to have a cast somewhere. (`Function.<T>identity()`, `(Function<T, T>) Function.identity())`, etc...)

btw, it's just about generic, it's has nothing to do with java-8/lambda expression.